# Android | Junit 4 Test crashes

Tags: java, android, gradle, junit4

I want to add tests to my android app project, but it always crashes.

here my gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 4
        versionName '1.1.2'

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

My TestClass (an empty test class):

```
package com.example;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Test extends TestCase {
    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

The error log:

```
 unable to enhance gradle daemon classloader with idea_rt.jar
 org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
 Could not resolve all files for configuration
 ':app:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'.
 org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1420)
 org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$3600(DefaultConfiguration.java:150)
 org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$DefaultResolutionHost.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:2032)
 org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:1392)
 org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:330)
 org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
 org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:64)
 org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection$UnresolvedItemsCollector.visitContents(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:372)
 org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:284)
 org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
 org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getFiles(AbstractFileCollection.java:130)
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
 Method)
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
 org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
 groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:63)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:329)
 ijresolvers1_12052bkonxwb33ouhf2odudmt$_run_closure2$_closure5.doCall(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ijresolvers1.gradle:121)
 jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown
 Source)
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
 org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
 groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
 groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
 groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
 groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:428)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2318)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2303)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2344)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$200.invoke(Unknown Source)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:247)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
 ijresolvers1_12052bkonxwb33ouhf2odudmt$_run_closure2.doCall(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ijresolvers1.gradle:117)
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
 Method)
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
 org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
 groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
 groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
 groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
 org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingClosure$1.lambda$run$0(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:180)
 org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication.reapply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:86)
 org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingClosure$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:177)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
 org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingClosure.doCall(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:174)
 jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown
 Source)
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
 org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
 groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
 groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
 groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
 groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
 org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:41)
 org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
 org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:43)
 org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:245)
 org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:157)
 org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:61)
 org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:346)
 org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:249)
 org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
 org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
 org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
 jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy41.graphPopulated(Unknown Source)
 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$NotifyTaskGraphWhenReady.run(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:457)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.lambda$fireWhenReady$1(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:437)
 org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
 org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:141)
 org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:128)
 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.fireWhenReady(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:436)
 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.populate(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:173)
 org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.prepareForTaskExecution(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:41)
 org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringTaskExecutionPreparer$CalculateTaskGraph.populateTaskGraph(BuildOperationFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.java:117)
 org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringTaskExecutionPreparer$CalculateTaskGraph.run(BuildOperationFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.java:68)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
 org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.prepareForTaskExecution(BuildOperationFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.java:56)
 org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareTaskExecution(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:233)
 org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:168)
 org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
 org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
 org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:71)
 org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
 org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
 org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:56)
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:66)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:90)
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
 org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
 org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:86)
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
 org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
 org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
 org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
 org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
 org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
 org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
 java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
 
 Caused by:
 org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not
 find org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:. Required by:
     project :app
```

Comment: According to the error, you are trying to use JUnit5, not 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could not find org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:. Required by: project :app

This is JUnit 5, not 4... And you would need a version added to this to use it

If you want to use JUnit **4**, and only in project test scope, remove these lines

```
implementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
```

Keep this

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
```

If you wanted to use JUnit5, check out - https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code was actually created by android studio automaticaly.

Comment: I don't think it automatically created two duplicate lines

Comment: Afterwards i deleted and recreated the test class yes.

Comment: Creating a class shouldn't modify the build artifacts like gradle files. Then again, I dont use Android Studio

Comment: With android studio you can let yourself autocreate an sceme test class. And this does all the gradle work and adds (but apparently not removes) dependecies.